# Counting number unique values in list by name/category

Tags: excel

I'm trying to count the number of unique values in a list, against a given name.

Example:

[image]

In this instance, Abi has 2 unique numbers, Barry has 1, Chrissy has 2, and Dave has 1.

I'm struggling to find an excel formula what I can put in column see and count the number of unique values for each name:

[image]

I've found that this formula gives the over number of unique numbers IF they numbers are actually numbers (you may noticed the little green triangles in the example.  Due to the way the numbers are generated, the numbers are stored as text):

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A1:A8;A1:A8)>0;1))
```

I tried this formula but came up with nothing but a #VALUE!, regardless of whether the numbers were text or not:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(E6:E14)>0;MATCH(E6:E14;E6:E14;0);""); IF(LEN(E6:E14)>0;MATCH(E6:E14;E6:E14;0);""))>0;1))
```

I've played around with the IF statement, SUMIF, COUNTIFS, but not hit that magic combination.

Can you help me?

Comment: You can copy columns A:B into a new column set, the perform on `Remove Duplicates` on both columns, then a `COUNTIF` on the name in the new column set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub UniqueTable()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, c As Collection, M As Long
    Dim j As Long, vd As String, va As String

    Columns("A:A").Copy Range("D1")

    ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    Range("E1").Value = "# of unique values"

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    M = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To N
        Set c = Nothing
        Set c = New Collection
        vd = Cells(i, "D").Value
        For j = 2 To M
            va = Cells(j, "A").Value
            If va = vd Then
                On Error Resume Next
                    c.Add Cells(j, "B").Value, CStr(Cells(j, "B").Value)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next j
        Cells(i, "E").Value = c.Count
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]